# Purple Flying Bee or Flying Purple Bee?

Tags: adjective-order

Which one is the right way to use as a document title, product name, or in any other "isolated" manner?

A bee that can fly and is purple. Not trying to imply it can

The second seems to imply someone is flying in the purple.

The first to me just does not sound right...

Comment: Related: [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order).

Comment: It is a "flying bee" that happens to be purple or a "purple bee" that happens to fly. You need to decide which quality has more importance, and that needs to directly precede "bee".

Comment: Don't all bees fly? Why is it worth calling this out at all?

Comment: Perhaps there are bees of many colors, and some are sitting idly by.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a purple bee that is currently flying, or a flying bee that is currently purple?

If it is a bee that that is currently flying and currently purple, you need a comma: "flying, purple bee" or "purple, flying bee" (probably the former, since color is more persistent).

Answer (score 1):

You may find useful the [order of adjectives](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order):

> 1. opinion
> 2. size
> 3. physical quality
> 4. shape
> 5. age
> 6. colour
> 7. origin
> 8. material
> 9. type
> 10. purpose

These are not grammar rules, but only a guide to what is most common.  In the case where an adjective can have several meanings. the order will help the reader understand which the writer means.

In this case "flying" could be either a physical quality of the bee, or the type of bee (if there were flying- and non-flying bees).  So either "purple flying bee" or "flying purple bee" is natural, depending on what you want to say.

There are exceptions.  Sometimes an adjective modifies another adjective in the description, and not the noun.  The more famous of these is the old song about a ["One-eyed one-horned flying purple people eater"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9H_cI_WCnE).  Is is a purple monster that eats people, or is it a monster that eats only *purple* people?

It turns out later in the song it is explained that the monster eats only purple people (whatever that means).  Otherwise it should have been a "one-eyed one-horned purple flying people eater."  Nevertheless, at the time, many assumed that the monster was itself purple in color, and drew pictures of it that way.

(Edit) One more important aspect of this.  Some nouns are *compound nouns* composed of two words that should remain together.  For example a "honey bee" is a description of a particular species of bee, and so should always be written that way regardless of other adjectives, "A purple flying honey bee" or "A purple flying worker honey bee".

Also as Malvolio points out, commas can help separate out confusing adjectives in a series, "A purple, flying, worker honey bee".  But the exact usage and placement of commas is entirely up to the individual writer.